# How can I turn off the nvidia splash on startup?

Tags: 12.10, nvidia

I'm using nvidia-current and I know it's not a big deal. But is it possible to disable to nvidia splash on startup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your xorg.conf you can enable the following option

```
Option "NoLogo" "True"
```

it will disable the boot screen as long as the configuration file doesn't change. Worked on my alienware m11x and macbook pro